# geojson data loaded into leaflet map and php/html page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I currently have an html page divided into 2 columns - the right side is a Leaflet map with markers and the left hand side describes a bit more about the markers. I load the Leaflet map using geoJson data on the right side and the map and markers display fine. Now I want to take the same geoJson data and use it to fill in the left side of the php page.  This way, only one file needs to be updated as we add sites.

Here is a sample of my geoJson data:

```
  var historicalMarkers = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-77.423603, 38.865608 ]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": 1,
               "siteName": "House14"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [ -77.416770, 38.923650]
            },
            "properties": {
                "id": 2,
               "siteName": "Meeting House"
            }
        }..........
```

On the main php page, I simply include my geoJson file (places.js) and my geoJson/Leaflet code (map-geoJson.js).

On this main php page, I would like descriptions of each of the markers.  In map-geoJson.js I am passing the data back to php via ajax like this:

```
    // get stuff ready for php
    var historicalData = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < historicalMarkers.features.length; i++) {
        var currentFeature = historicalMarkers.features[i];
        var id = currentFeature.properties.id;
        var siteName = currentFeature.properties.siteName;

        console.log(id, siteName);
        historicalData.push({ id: id, siteName : siteName });
    }
    var historicalJson = JSON.stringify(historicalData);

    $.ajax({
        url: location.pathname,   //current page
        type: 'POST',
        data: historicalJson
    });
```

The data is displayed on the console and is correct.  On my php page, I want to grab the data and put it into several different divs on the page:

```
 $phpArray = json_decode($_POST['historicalJson']);
 var_dump ($phpArray);                // NULL is displayed 
  foreach ( $phpArray as $value )
  {  ?>
     <div class="id">
        <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $value['id']; ?></a></h4>
     </div>
     <div class="siteName">
        <h4><a href="#"><?php echo $value['siteName']; ?></a></h4>
     </div>

......
  <?php } ?>
```

But nothing is displayed.  I've also tried echo'ing

```
    echo $value[0]->id;
    echo $value['id']
```

Somehow I am not grabbing the data correctly in the php page and echo'ing it into the div.
Can anyone lend a suggestion?  I'm sure it is something small I am missing, but I've tried many, many ways to grab the data in php.
Thanks

Comment: What's the value of `historicalMarkers` at runtime?

Comment: historicalMarkers contains my geoJson data.  (Is that what you mean?)

Comment: No, I mean the actual value you get from debugging at runtime. What's the output of a `console.log(historicalMarkers)`?

Comment: It's an object with all the info.  I uploaded code to test site if that helps:   [link](http://steppingstonez.com/test/test-json.php)

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` returns an object (`stdClass`) per default. If you want to use the data as an array, you need to set the second parameter of the function to `true` :

```
 $phpArray = json_decode($_POST['historicalJson'], true);
```

See [json_decode documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Darn, missed that.  However, when I do that, then `var_dum($phpArray)`, I still get a NULL response.  I do see the data coming back in Firefox's Console -> XHR->Params:  `[{"id":1,"siteName":"House"},{"id":2,"siteName":"House2"}] `

Comment: probably a typo `$_POST['data']` instead of `$_POST['historicalJson']` : `historicalJson` is your javascript variable, but you send it into `data`

Comment: yes, it was a typo - I had $_POST['data']. Still nada. I uploaded code to test site if that helps:   [link](http://steppingstonez.com/test/test-json.php)